# Confused about a Javascript closure case

Tags: javascript, mongodb, node.js, closures

I am writing some node.js code using the node-mongodb driver. I decided to cache the collection objects when I obtain them like this:

```
var db = connectionObject;

function getCollection(collectionName) {
    return function(callback) {
        var cache;

        if (cache) return callback(null, cache);

        db.collection(collectionName, function(err, collection) {
            return err ? callback(err) : callback(null, cache = collection);
        });
    }
}

var usersCollection = getCollection('users');
usersCollection(function(err, collection) {
    collection.find({}); // Rest of code here ...
});
```

Repeated calls of the usersCollection function should use the cached collection object, except that it doesn't - the cache variable is always undefined. Changing the code to this fixes the problem:

```
return function(callback) {
    var cache = arguments.callee;

    if (cache.cached) return callback(null, cache.cached);

    db.collection(collectionName, function(err, collection) {
        return err ? callback(err) : callback(null, cache.cached = collection);
    });
}
```

I am still confused about why the 'cache' variable goes out of scope. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use jsbeautifier or jsfiddle to format your code properly before posting it. It improves readability.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
function getCollection(collectionName) {
    var cache;
    return function(callback) {
```

instead of what you have right now:

```
function getCollection(collectionName) {
    return function(callback) {
        var cache;
```

Comment: If I put cache in the getCollection function it will get overwritten by different collection objects in the case of: getCollection('users'), getCollection('posts'), getCollection('pages')

Comment: @Discodancer - no, it won't -- each call to "getCollection()" will have its own "cache" variable.

Comment: You can not use cache until getCollection response. You have to find a way out to make you code wait the response.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing closes over `cache` after the function returned from `getCollection` (`usersCollection`) executes. There is no function that is returned from that scope.

`cache` needs to be defined outside of the `usersCollection` function for any reference to it to be captured.